# Line Plot subset data with ggplot2 (facet)

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, facet

I have test score data.  I want ggline plot for 3 different test scores in reading over various years (3 lines). I would like this stacked over 4 different test scores in writing the same years (4 lines).  Having all 7 on one plot is confusing to read.
I can subset the data so it shows either reading or writing, but I can't seem to stack them over top of each other neatly.

year, ID, test, score , type

2010, 1, R1, 72.75, R
2010, 1, R2, 68.25, R 
2010, 1, R3, 83.75, R 
2010, 1, W1, 89.25, W 
2010, 1, W2, 58.25, W 
2010, 1, W3, 64.25, W 
2010, 1, W4, 90.25, W 
2011, 1, R1, 52.25, R 
2011, 1, R2, 90.25, R 
2011, 1, R3, 73.25, R 
2011, 1, W1, 79.5, W 
2011, 1, W2, 89.25, W 
2011, 1, W3, 85.25, W 
2011, 1, W4, 78.25, W

…

I have this code to produce one graph with just reading:

```
ggplot(subset(df,skill %in% c("R1", "R2", "R3"))) + 
  geom_line(aes(year, score, group=skill, colour=skill))
```

I have tried to do this to get both, but it obviously is incorrect:

```
p1 <- subset(df,skill %in% c("R1", "R2", "R3"))
p2 <- subset(df,skill %in% c("W1", "W2", "W3", "W4"))
ggplot()+ geom_line(data=p1, aes(year, score, group=skill, colour=skill)) +
  geom_line(data=p2, aes(year, score, group=skill, colour=skill)) +
  facet_grid(~type)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your example data has a column `test` but your code is referring to a column `skill` which is not in your example data. 

Please use `dput(df))` and copy the output to your question so that it is easier for people to work with the data as you have it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Try changing your plot code to use the whole dataset ("df") in a single `geom_line` layer plus the facets rather than having a separate `geom_line` layer per subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to facet based on type, you don't need to subset the data into p1 and p2.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(year, score, group = skill, colour = skill)) +
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

Alternative, adding `nrow =2` to stack the plots and `scales = "free"` to give them independent axes.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(year, score, group = skill, colour = skill)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, nrow = 2, scales = "free")
```

However, your comment says

> This does work but it puts the graph side by side instead of stacked vertically. Is there a way to stack them one on top of the other and perhaps separate the legend so reading and writing are separate?

To address the separate legend, I would make each plot, and then combine using the package `cowplot`. Other ways to do this using `gridExtra` but `cowplot` makes this simple.

```
p1 <- ggplot(subset(df,skill %in% c("R1", "R2", "R3"))) + 
  geom_line(aes(year, score, group = skill, colour = skill)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, scales = "free")

p2 <- ggplot(subset(df,type %in% c("W"))) + 
  geom_line(aes(year, score, group = skill, colour = skill)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, scales = "free")

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2)
```

Comment: thank you Eric for your response.  This does work but it puts the graph side by side instead of stacked vertically.  Is there a way to stack them one on top of the other and perhaps separate the legend so reading and writing are separate?

Comment: Updated answer, I think this addresses your comment.